# Snap to Grid unexpected result

Tags: snapping

I was working with the Snap to Grid option and due to the unexpected result obtained I would like to show you the case that can be summarized as follows:

- I take a Cube (2x2x2).
- Set the Z dimension in 0.
- I set the Cube in Edit Mode and selected a vertex that was move to the right side.
- I made “Snap to Grid” and the result was the vertex goes to the Object Origin and not to the nearest grid intersection.

In the following link there is a PDF with pictures that illustrate the case:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1emiHzIWh8eMzZNTFBHWHc5Y0U

Cordially,
Ricardo Amaya R.

Answer (score 1):

When You set **Z dimension** to 0, it makes **z-scale** automatically to 0. It means that all Z - coordinates in model will multiply by 0:

```
 global coordinates = local coordinates * scale
```

When you select “**Snap to Grid**” it snaps globaly, and global coordinates needs to convert to local.  That means if you have scale 0.5 local coordinates must by twice bigger. So, the formula is:

```
local coordinates = global coordinates / scale
```

So, if you set **scale** to 0 the formula will be:

```
local coordinates = global coordinates / 0
```

But division by zero is mathematically impossible. So it will raze an exception that reset coordinates.

See also: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)